# Concentric Rainbow Squares

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics

I want to make this image using `turtle`,

[image: Picture of result]

This is what I have so far, but there are multiple errors.

```
import turtle
import colorsys
import random

def draw_circle(x,y,r,color):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.seth(0)
    turtle.goto(x,y-r)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(r)
    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_square(x,y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.seth(0)
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for i in range(2):
        turtle.fd(w)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.fd(h)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()


turtle.speed(0)

x = 0
y = -200

for i in range(100):
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(x,1,1)
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    draw_square(x,y)
    x += .01
    y += 10
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MBach/Documents/concentric squares.py", line 39, in <module>
    draw_square(x,y)
  File "/Users/MBach/Documents/concentric squares.py", line 24, in draw_square
    turtle.fd(w)
NameError: name 'w' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question is too broad. Please be more specific in some of your "multiple errors." Show us, at least, the full traceback from the first error message. If none, show us the output from your code. In other words, read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "multiple errors". Uh, that's not even correctly indented. I suggest going to https://opentechschool.github.io/python-beginners/en/simple_drawing.html for a good intro to understand how to draw rectangles with `turtle`. Also pay close attention to your indentation, because python's execution depends on it.

Comment: `turtle.fd(w)` where is `w` defined? It isn't. Neither is `h`.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for @darksky's solution to complete ;-) I wrote this alternate example which uses *stamping* instead of *drawing* to simplify the code and speed up the graphics:

```
import turtle
import colorsys

STEP = 2  # distance between squares
WIDTH = 375  # width of the biggest square

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def draw_square(width, color):
    turtle.shapesize(width / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.shape('square')
turtle.fillcolor('white')

hue = 0

for width in range(WIDTH, 0, -2 * STEP):
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, 1, 1)
    draw_square(width, color)
    hue += 0.01

turtle.done()
```

Stamping isn't the solution to all turtle problems but simple geometric drawings like this, it has its advantages:

[image]

Comment: Nice moiré pattern @cdlane

Answer (score 0):

Aside from indentation, there are some problems here that indicate you might have copy pasted some of this code randomly from somewhere without paying close attention to what it does. For example this for loop:

```
for i in range(2):
    turtle.fd(w)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(h)
    turtle.left(90)
```

contains variables `w` and `h`, but these are not defined in your code. Let's first understand how to draw a square. There are two steps turtle must do:

1. Go to a given coordinate (x, y)
2. Trace out the shape of a square by making four 90 degree turns.

To go to a coordinate without drawing anything, we have to lift the pen with `turtle.penup()`, go there with `turtle.goto()` and put the pen down with `turtle.pendown()`. So your `draw_square` should look something like this:

```
def draw_square(x, y, width):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.right(90)
```

Next, let's look at this second for loop that you wrote:

```
x = 0
y = -200

for i in range(100):
  color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(x, 1, 1)
  turtle.pencolor(color)
  draw_square(x, y)
  x += .01
  y += 10
```

You have somewhat the right idea. Start with an x, y coordinate, update it in each iteration, update a color, and draw a square. There are several problems, however. First of all, while x must increase, y must actually **decrease**. This is because as you go from top of the screen to the bottom, y value decreases. Secondly, the amount by which they have to change has to be equal, since squares are concentric.

Let's define a `step`, that is distance between squares, `width`, the size of the square, an initial position, and we have to make sure `hue` gets incremented much slower than x and y.

```
step = 3 # distance between squares
width = 600 #width of the biggest square
x, y = -width / 2,  width / 2 
hue = 0

for i in range(100):
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, 1, 1)
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    draw_square(x, y, width)
    x += step
    y -= step
    width -= 2 * step
    hue += 0.01
```